# Tuning the below Sql query

Tags: oracle, database-performance, performance

I have a database of Old version Oracle 8.1.7 there I have been running the below Union query

```
select c_ordine_es
         ,c_ordine_salesnet
         ,v_oyov
         ,v_annuale
         ,v_oneoff
         ,v_canone
         ,c_operatore_tam
     from v_ordine_cliente_easysell

    where d_ultima_modifica>DataRif
    union
   select c_ordine_es
         ,c_ordine_salesnet
         ,v_oyov
         ,v_annuale
         ,v_oneoff
         ,v_canone
         ,c_operatore_tam
     from v_ordine_cliente_easysell v
         ,scarti_interfaccia_easysell_o s
    where s.c_codice_es=v.c_ordine_es
      and s.t_tabella_es=pkType.K_SCARTO_ORDINE_CLIENTE;
```

Every time I run these query the SQL Client(I am using Toad) hangs. Here I must mention data in `v_ordine_cliente_easysell` and `scarti_interfaccia_easysell_o` these two views/synonyms are fetched using DB Link(To another SIEBEL DB). I guess the problem is happening at the time of fetching data via DB_LINK, as the SIEBEL DB is alwas very busy.  Would you please suggest me how could I tune the above query?

The Explain plan goes like below

```
OPERATION          OPTIONS  OBJECT_NODE POSITION    COST    CARDINALITY BYTES
SELECT STATEMENT            28  28  478912  61779648
HASH JOIN           1   28  478912  61779648
INDEX   FAST FULL SCAN      1   2   11354   102186
REMOTE      SIEB.WORLD  2   23  4218    506160
```

Comment: maybe you need `UNION ALL`, not `UNION`.

Comment: Thanks @FlorinGhita , I tried it. But I guess problem is with the 2nd part of the query. It is taking too much time fetching the data when I run it singularly. Is there any suggesion how could I improve the data fetching performance from DB LINK?

Comment: **8.1.7.**? Really? That has been out of support for ages. To get any useful feedback you should post the execution plan for the query.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I have added it above. Though in a hefty manner but still. I guess if you just copy paste in somewhere may be in Excel, it will display properly.

Comment: thanks @a_horse_with_no_name I think as the no of cardinalities are very high. That might be causing the excessive time it is taking. Any idea how to tackle this?

Comment: I think this is only caused by the DBLink. Probably a very slow connection. Unfortunately you pasted the execution plan with all indention removed so it's nearly impossible to read.

Comment: @Subhamoy you stated the two objects (v_ordline and scarti) were synonyms pointing to a remote database table or view. the plan shows a fast full scan occuring locally, so what table is that against? are you running a slightly different SQL? also was that plan for the 2nd part of the union only?

Comment: @DazzaL: Is there anyway I could forward the Explain_Plan? May be through email or anything? I tried to copy paste in tabular manner but sadly I could not. I am running the whole sql. Through DB Link the view v_ordline and Scarti are created.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make a local copy of table `v_ordine_cliente_easysell`.
2. Make a local copy of table `scarti_interfaccia_easysell_o` filtered with
   `t_tabella_es=pkType.K_SCARTO_ORDINE_CLIENTE`.
3. Run the query on local copies, but using `UNION ALL`